# How to align floated buttons in same row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the button and links in floated UL list. However it seems they are not getting properly aligned. [Note: we have one link and other is form button].

Following is code and [link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbrBwV):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Hello</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


div{
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul li{
  float:right;
  list-style:none;
}
a, button{
  padding: 4px;
  border:1px solid green;
  margin-left:5px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `li` elements aren't getting aligned properly is because of what's inside them.
You have one `button` and one `a`-tag. Buttons are by default displayed as a block-element while a-tags are displayed as an inline-element.

This results in your button and your link having different padding because top/bottom padding doesn't show on `inline` elements.

You can easily solve this by adding `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your css rule.

```css
div{
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
}
ul:after{content: '.'; visibility:hidden; height:0; display:block; clear:both;}
ul li{
  float:right;
  list-style:none;
}
a, button{
  padding: 4px;
  border:1px solid green;
  margin-left:5px;
  font-size:12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Hello</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`

the issue was because of `float:right` by using `display:inline-block` element adjusts to the width of its children and you can `align` it by adding `text-align`

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:right;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
a,
button {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Hello</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

pls give display:block for a(anchor) tag.if you use padding or margin(etc..) in anchor tag.we need to use display.

Comment: adding block to anchor would force use of width or it would be 100% width ... which I am not sure helping anyways